# Unexpected behavior with qbinom

Tags: r

Consider the following case:

```
qbinom(p=0.05,size=6040:6045,prob=0.995)
[1] 6001 6041 6042 6043 6004 6005
```

the quantile for n=6041,6042,6043 are 6041,6042 and 6043, respectively. This does not seems right for `p=0.05`.

Let's verify the result for n=6041 with `pbinom`:

```
pbinom(q=6000:6041,size=6041,prob=0.995)
 [1] 0.03490172 0.04974803 0.06943756 0.09489324 0.12695452 0.16626629
 [7] 0.21315764 0.26752726 0.32875643 0.39567139 0.46657229 0.53933683
[13] 0.61159304 0.68094122 0.74519263 0.80258630 0.85194713 0.89275986
[19] 0.92514962 0.94977961 0.96769159 0.98012377 0.98834033 0.99349835
[25] 0.99656542 0.99828757 0.99919751 0.99964817 0.99985646 0.99994584
[31] 0.99998123 0.99999408 0.99999832 0.99999957 0.99999991 0.99999998
[37] 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000
```

6002 is the first quantile that is above 0.05. This contradicts with the results in `qbinom`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you provide your sessionInfo? I can't reproduce it with R 4.0.2

Comment: @starja I am running on 4.2.2. I just tested it on 4.0.3 and qbinom works as intended.

Comment: `qbinom` was updated in 4.1.1. Not sure if that is the root cause.

Comment: It's probably best to file a bug with R: https://bugs.r-project.org/

Comment: You should report the bug, but read this first:  https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html

Answer (score 1):

The binomial distribution has two parameters, size (number of trials) and probability of success for each trial. You are holding the `prob` constant between the two calls, but not the size parameter.

The number of trials is different between the two functions. In the call to `qbinom` you asking for the quantile at given probability for trial sizes between 6040-6045. In the call to `pbinom` you are asking for different quantiles for a fixed trial size, 6041.

What you want to do to check is

```r
purrr::map2_dbl(
  qbinom(p=0.05,size=6040:6045,prob=0.995),
  6040:6045, 
  \(q, size) pbinom(q, size, prob = 0.995)
)
#> [1] 0.06931045 1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000 0.05004380 0.05014268
```

Theses probabilities are all above 5%. The high probability of success of each trial makes this a VERY skewed distribution. There is a very narrow range of outcomes with any appreciable probability of occurring.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. the probability for n=6041,6042and 6043 are way above 5%. Running your code in R 4.0.3 yields:```[1] 0.06931045 0.06943756 0.06956484 0.06969228 0.05004380 0.05014268```